# Python Sklearn - Use RFE and GridSearch with ClassifierChain

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is it possible to use [`RFE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) and [`GridSearch`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) together with [`ClassifierChain`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.ClassifierChain.html)?

A short snippet of my current approach:

```
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=7, test_size=600, random_state=1)
clf = ClassifierChain(LinearSVC(), order='random', cv=sss, random_state=3)

rfe = RFE(estimator=clf, step=100, n_features_to_select=0.93)
features_array = rfe.fit_transform(features_array, labels_data.values.ravel())

parameters = {
    "clf__base_estimator": (LinearSVC(C=1e-20), ),
    "clf__order": ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6],),
    "clf__cv": (sss, ),
    "clf__random_state": (None, 0, 1, 2)
}

pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', clf)])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, scoring = scoring, refit = 'rec', n_jobs=-1, cv=sss, error_score='raise', return_train_score=True, verbose=True)

grid_search.fit(features_array, labels_data.values.ravel())
```

This doesn't work, after executing I get a huge load of exceptions. I use Anaconda Jupyter Notebook so there are also exceptions from the runtime environment.
Maybe you guys cut through the problem and will see on first glance what the problem is, otherwise I will post the exceptions.

Edit: New approach without RFE:

```
scoring = {'rec': 'recall', 'acc': 'accuracy', 'prec': 'precision', 'rocauc': 'roc_auc'}
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(#stuff)
features_array = tfidf.fit_transform(clean_features_ref)

clf = ClassifierChain(LinearSVC(), order='random', cv=sss, random_state=3)

parameters = {
    'base_estimator__C': (1e-14,1e-10, 1e-4)
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring = scoring, refit = 'rec', n_jobs=-1, cv=sss,
                           error_score='raise', return_train_score=True, verbose =True)

grid_search.fit(features_array, labels_data.values.ravel())
```

Edit_2: So I just found out that this isn't working already:

```
clf = ClassifierChain(LinearSVC(), order='random', cv=sss, random_state=3)
clf.fit(features_array, labels_data.values.ravel())
```

with

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Can you provide an example of the exceptions you're getting?

Comment: 1) The signatures of `fit()` method in `RFE` and `ClassifierChain` are different. `RFE` can only take single array as `y` whereas `ClassifierChain` wants 2-d `y` (a label indicator matrix). 2) `RFE` requires an estimator with `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute after the training. `ClassifierChain` dont have that. So no, you cannot use `ClassifierChain` with `RFE`

Comment: @VivekKumar Is it possible to use `ClassifierChain` without `RFE` but still with `GridSearch`?

Comment: Yes. But you need to carefully choose the `scoring`.

Comment: My scoring looks like this: `scoring = {'rec': 'recall', 'acc': 'accuracy', 'prec': 'precision', 'rocauc': 'roc_auc'}`. I updated my initial post of how my approach looks like without RFE - but still with a lot of error messages.

Comment: Post those error messages. There are a lot of possibilities here. Maybe the StratifiedShuffleSplit dont work with your data? Can you show some samples of `labels_data`?